# Rendering Problems in android studio xml files

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio, custom-view

How to fix the following?

> "The following classes could not be instantiated:"

If I don't close this warning the preview cannot show the custom widget, but it's ok when run the project.

Comment: please update your full problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio may have issues to render your custom views which has overwritten onCreate methods.

To avoid this issues, you can add `if(isInEditMode)` to lines that causes this problem in onCreate.

Good luck there.

Comment: I guess some codes effects the view in Runtime. Thats the why Studio can show it properly without running.